# XPath Query local-name() - fetch tag based on other tag's value

Tags: xpath

I've the below xml format. I need to fetch 'typename1' and I wrote //*[local-name() = 'type-name' and text() ='typeName1']. Can somebody help me how to fetch 'objectid1' if 'type-name' is 'typeName1' using XPath Query expression.

```
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/API/xsl/abcde.xml" ?>
    <name xmlns="http://www.ccc.org/2011/SSS" xmlns:hostmgmt='http://www.xyzw.com/abcd'>
       <title type="text">test</title>   
       <content>
          <id>48035</id>      
          <host-contacts>
             <host-contact>
                <host-contact-type>Employee</host-contact-type>
                <host-contact-role>Role</host-contact-role>
                <host-contact-name>Employee Name</host-contact-name>
             </host-contact>
          </host-contacts>
          <syslog-messages>N</syslog-messages>      
          <services>
             <service>            
                <objectid>objectid1</objectid>
                <type-name>typeName1</type-name>
             </service>
             <service>            
                <objectid>objectid2</objectid>
                <type-name>typeName2</type-name>
             </service>
          </services>
          <building>ABC</building>
          <asset>XYZ</asset>
       </content>
    </name>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following xpath

```
//*[local-name()='service'][child::*[local-name()='type-name'][.='typeName1']]/*[local-name()='objectid']/text()
```

it says find a node's (with a local-name of `service`) (with a child's local-name of `type-name` who's value is equals to "typeName1") child content with a local-name of `objectid`

Comment: Thanks for the response, working as expected. I'm new to XPath Query syntaxes, can you please explain the above expression. I'm not sure whether the tag 'objectid' always precedes the tag 'type-name'. Is there any other alternate way?

Comment: please close this question by accepting the answer, click the check mark on the left, under the arrowheads.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just declare the namespace and use normal axis steps instead of `local-name()` hacks (that ignore namespaces)? Declaring namespaces is different in different programming languages, but for most of them rather straight-forward and easy.

```
//sss:service[sss:type-name='typeName1']/sss:objectid
```

Comment: I tried, but getting an error 'Error:DOMXPath::evaluate() [<a href='domxpath.evaluate'>domxpath.evaluate</a>]: Invalid expression'. Hence tried with local-name()

Comment: It seems you're using XPath in PHP with DOMXPath. Registering namespaces is very easy there. Maybe you should better post the code you're having problems with instead of looking for a workaround, I'm pretty sure we'll find an easy solution for it. Best would be to edit it into your question.

Comment: There is no change in the syntax, just addition of namespace before the tags. Anyway here is the one:

Comment: <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/API/xsl/abcde.xml" ?>
<name xmlns="http://www.ccc.org/2011/SSS" xmlns:hostmgmt='http://www.xyzw.com/abcd'>
   <title type="text">test</title>   
   <content>
      <ns:id>48035</ns:id>
      <ns:host-contacts>
         <ns:host-contact>
            <ns:host-contact-type>Employee</ns:host-contact-type>
            <ns:host-contact-role>Role</ns:host-contact-role>
            <ns:host-contact-name>Employee Name</ns:host-contact-name>
         </ns:host-contact>
      </ns:host-contacts>
      <ns:syslog-messages>N</ns:syslog-messages>

Comment: <ns:services>
         <ns:service>            
            <ns:objectid>objectid1</ns:objectid>
            <ns:type-name>typeName1</ns:type-name>
         </ns:service>
         <ns:service>            
            <ns:objectid>objectid2</ns:objectid>
            <ns:type-name>typeName2</ns:type-name>
         </ns:service>
      </ns:services>
      <ns:building>ABC</ns:building>
      <ns:asset>XYZ</ns:asset>
   </content>
</name>

Comment: not allowed to copy entire xml, hence pasted several times.

Comment: Please, don't put code into comments, it's unreadable in here. Edit your question instead. And also post the PHP code you're having problems with. Have a look on what a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) is.

Answer (score 0):

try this.. 
//service[type-name="typeName1"]/objectid
another example can be 
//*[local-name() = 'type-name' and text() ='typeName1']/objectid

Comment: Is there any modification to be done to the above expression if there is any Namespace?